# returning an array filtered from an existing array

Tags: java, arrays, null, return

So here's the question I need to answer: Implement a method that takes a research area as an input and returns the names of scientists associated with that area.

I've got a lot of the base code necessary but am struggling because I am trying to filter out the array of scientist professions to only return the scientist whose profession is the specified input. What I need help with is finding a way to make a new array with only certain filtered scientists and excluding the unspecified scientist. Any idea on how to change the code to return an array of only certain scientists would be very helpful! The issue is in the CheckField method, and I'll put my code below of the program:

```
public class computerScientists {

    String name;
    String researchArea;
    String contribution;

    // Constructor
    public computerScientists(String NM, String RA, String C) {
        this.name = NM;
        this.researchArea = RA;
        this.contribution = C;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        computerScientists[] personDatabase = {
            new computerScientists("Katherine Johnson", "Mathematician", "Mathmetician for NASA during space race"),
            new computerScientists("Kimberely Bryant", "Entrepreneur & Activist", "Founded black girls code"),
            new computerScientists("Mark Dean", "Inventor and Engineer", "Helped design and release some of the first computers"),
            new computerScientists("Marie Van Brittan Brown", "Inventor and Pioneer", "Pieneered and invented an audio-video alarm system"),
            new computerScientists("Marian R Croak", "Engineer", "Helped develop the Voice Over Internet Protocol (VOIP)")
        };
        //int size = person1.length
        for(int i=0; i<personDatabase.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Innovator " + String.valueOf(i + 1) + ": \n");
            System.out.println("Name: " + personDatabase[i].name + "\n"
                + "Research Area: " + personDatabase[i].researchArea + "\n"
                + "Contribution: " + personDatabase[i].contribution);
            System.out.println();
        }
        checkField("Inventor", personDatabase);
    }
    public static computerScientists[] checkField(String researchField, computerScientists[] array1) {
        computerScientists[] newArray1 = new computerScientists[array1.length];
        //int difference = newArray1.length - array1.length;
        for (int i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            if (array1[i].researchArea.contains(researchField)) {
                newArray1[i].researchArea = String.valueOf(array1[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int j=0; j<newArray1.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(newArray1[j].researchArea);
        }
        return newArray1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using arrays rather than `List`s?

Comment: I'm not too informed on java, and we've only learned arrays so it was my assumption we had to do it with arrays. I looked a bit more into lists like you had recommended and swapped all my logic to lists rather than arrays and the program is working great now. Thanks a lot for the recommendation!